# SVProgressHUD background around loading is missing ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, svprogresshud

Since I upgraded to iOS 7 the background of the loading box is no longer showing. See screenshot:[image]

I added the library using Cocoapods and am on version 1.0

My .m file has the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Logging in..." maskType: SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and it's possibly a bug.

Just change your pod version to

```
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
```

That should fix the problem